# Display title with React Helmet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, gatsby, react-helmet

I'm using [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/)'s inclusion of [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) to display `<title />` and `<meta />` tags in the `<head />`. What I'd really like to do is send the same title to my global `<Header />` component so the title is displayed in the actual text of the page as well as in the head. How would I accomplish something like this with React? I'm used to Ember where I can just set a `pageTitle` property on the Application controller/route and pass it down to components as well as update the `<head />` values with something like ember-wormhole.

I understand I could use Flux for a global state or I could pass setTitle to my page components and they could send up a setTitle action on each Page component's `componentDidMount`, but is there a better way to handle this? Perhaps with React Router 4?

So far, I was able to pull in the location context like so:

```
const TemplateWrapper = (args) => {
  const { children, location } = args
  return (
    <div>
      <Helmet title={location.pathname} />
      <Header title={location.pathname} />
      <div>
        {children()}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

So I could add a function in there to lookup a page title based on the path, but I'd like the "Title" of the page to be set globally instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Helmet has an `onChangeClientState` property that can be used to get the newState when a `<Helmet>` component changes state.

Using the example in the post's question:

```js
class Template extends Component {
  state = {
    title: 'Default Title'
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Helmet onChangeClientState={(newState) => this.setState({ title: newState.title }) } />
        <Header title={this.state.title} />
        <div>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This way if you set title in a sub-component with `<Helmet>` the global `title` state will change to reflect and update the title elsewhere in the app.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/blob/master/README.md#reference-guide), it's actually supposed to be `onChangeClientState`